# Sorting ManyToMany field automatically in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I currently have a set of models that look similar to this contrived code:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
    topping = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, through="PizzaToppings")

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class PizzaToppings(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering=["order_to_add_topping"]

    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
    order_to_add_topping = models.IntegerField()
```

My problem is that what happens when I attempt to access the toppings of a pizza in the order specified in the PizzaToppings ManyToMany extra fields table.  Assume the pizza has cheese and ham, with the order_to_add_topping in the PizzaToppings data set to 0 and 1 respectively:

```
>>> pizza = Pizza.objects.get(pk=490)
>>> pizza.toppings.all()[0].name
'Ham'
```

That should say 'Cheese'.  I would have thought the RelationManager would have respected the `ordering` Meta class field, but it appears it doesn't.  So I guess accessing the name of the first topping added to the pizza shouldn't be done with `pizza.toppings.all()[0].name`.

How should it be accessed?  Is the problem with my model query or is it how I have my models set up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your model is fine you just need to query the relationship since now you have a "through" relationship with extra fields. The relationship is created automatically as topping_relationship in your case, so your query should be:

```
pizza.toppings.order_by('topping_relationship__order_to_add_topping')
```

Comment: nearly lifesaver, but how would you do this in a template? Your solution is console based. ON console I get [<Topping:top1>,<Topping: ...]. How can I access the topping, "name" does not work.

Comment: I got it. But another issue: how would you do this if toppings has a foreign key field and you need access to it? E.g. toppings has "resource" as fk. Then pizza.toppings does not work because you only get the toping.